# How to add 2 to a value every time another value goes up by 1?

Tags: typescript, ionic3

I am designing an app that offers some services and for every 1 hour you have to pay 2$. The least amount of time you can book is 3 hours(so starting price is 6$) and the highest is 8 hours, I am trying to write some code where It would check the amount of hours the user entered and output the price accordingly.

I solved this by creating multiple if statements for each scenario from 3-8 but I am looking for a way to minimize the code.

```
 if(hours == 3){
        this.Price = 6;
      } 
      if(hours == 4){
        this.Price = 8;
      } 
  .
  .
  .
    if(hours == 8){
        this.Price = 16;
      }
```

Comment: Is the title confusing? I am reading it as add 2 to the value of price every time the amount of hours goes up by 1.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't thought about it that way. But still... `Price` is twice the amount of `hours`. Why don't you use this correlation?

Comment: Yeah for some reason I did not notice that, made the problem seem way bigger in my head than it actually was. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is crazy simple.

If you look at your code, you can easily see that the **price is hours multipled by 2**.

Just use:

```js
this.Price = hours * 2;
```

Comment: I actually cannot believe I did not notice that thank you.